# Sum to columns in csv and give the result in a 3rd column with Powershell

Tags: powershell, sum

I´m in need to sum to columns by identifier and show the result in a 3rd column.

Something like this.

**The data in the csv look like this**(real data):

```
"PagesBW";"PagesColor";"Filename"
"238119";"86099";"A01 25-08-2020"
"78270";"32262";"A02 25-08-2020"
"158";"933";"A04 25-08-2020"
"510";"82";"A05 25-08-2020"
```

***The result i want is this***

```
"Filename";"PagesBW";"PagesColor";"Total"
"A01 25-08-2020";"238119";"86099";"324218"
"A02 25-08-2020";"78270";"32262";"110527"
"A04 25-08-2020";"158";"933";"1091"
"A05 25-08-2020";"510";"82";"592"
```

**I manage to write this :**

```
$COUNT = import-csv "C:\temp\test\testcount\finalfile3.csv" -Delimiter ";" -Encoding UTF8
$COUNT | Select-Object  Filename, PagesBW, PagesColor, @{Name="Total";e={ $_.PagesBW + $_.PagesColor}}| Export-Csv -Delimiter ";" -Path "C:\temp\test\testcount\new.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

**But with this i got , this:**

```
"PagesBW";"PagesColor";"TOTAL";"Filename"
"2";"1";"21";"A"
"2";"5";"25";"B"
```

Instead of sum, what does , is putting together the numbers.

Can i get some advice or help. Please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Change `@{Name="Total";e={ $_.PagesBW + $_.PagesColor}}` to `@{Name="Total";e={ [decimal]$_.PagesBW + $_.PagesColor}}` or `@{Name="Total";e={ [int]$_.PagesBW + $_.PagesColor}}`. Use `[int]` if you only have integers. Use `[decimal]` if you have fractional numbers. Do not translate anything other than your column names. What we're doing is [casting a String to an integer or decimal](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.1#cast-operator--). Only the first column should be necessary to cast. The rest are implied.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Import-Csv outputs strings. If you want to calculate with the values you will have to cast them to a number type like [INT] for example.
Like this:

```
$Count = @'
"PagesBW";"PagesColor";"Filename"
"2";"1";"A"
"2";"5";"B"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

$COUNT | 
Select-Object  Filename, PagesBW, PagesColor, @{Name='Total';Expression={ [INT]$_.PagesBW + [INT]$_.PagesColor}}| 
Export-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path 'C:\temp\test\testcount\new.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Of course you can keep your code to import your csv file like this:

```
$COUNT = import-csv 'C:\temp\test\testcount\finalfile3.csv' -Delimiter ';' -Encoding UTF8
$COUNT | 
    Select-Object  Filename, PagesBW, PagesColor, @{Name='Total';Expression={ [INT]$_.PagesBW + [INT]$_.PagesColor}}| 
    Export-Csv -Delimiter ';' -Path 'C:\temp\test\testcount\new.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Checked with the newly posted sample data and it still works:

```
$Count = @'
"PagesBW";"PagesColor";"Filename"
"238119";"86099";"A01 25-08-2020"
"78270";"32262";"A02 25-08-2020"
"158";"933";"A04 25-08-2020"
"510";"82";"A05 25-08-2020"
'@ | ConvertFrom-Csv -Delimiter ';'

$COUNT | 
Select-Object  Filename, PagesBW, PagesColor, @{Name='Total';Expression={ [INT]$_.PagesBW + [INT]$_.PagesColor}}
```

The output I get is this:

```
Filename       PagesBW PagesColor  Total
--------       ------- ----------  -----
A01 25-08-2020 238119  86099      324218
A02 25-08-2020 78270   32262      110532
A04 25-08-2020 158     933          1091
A05 25-08-2020 510     82            592
```

Comment: But in @´ i have to put all the data by hand?  In the example, was only two lines, but in reality there are more than 47 lines. I need this do be done by  powershell in a task. The taks will find the file , then sum with this function , then let the new file with the sum.

Comment: The `$Count = @'` bit was only to build sample data to be able to test your code, CSV-sample etc. Pay attention to the `Select-Object` line and how it differs from yours.

Comment: Hi, i used your line and i got this:"Filename";"PagesBW";"PagesColor";"Total"
"A";;;"0"
"B";;;"0"

Comment: The result still 0 even with the new code you put it.

Comment: @Olaf i eddited, and put real examples from the file. try again with your code and let me know. cause i copy paste your  code into a new sheet of powershell and it gaves me o instead of the sum

Comment: Yes, but for the purpose of this chat, i changed in english for you. But in my script i changed  back in spanish. Still 0

Comment: I think we don´t understand each other, i already ask you this, i have to manualy input all the data from the original csv in @? You said no, so you gave me the second part that is exactly like me script but with the [INT]. So what i have to do? Cause i dont want to add manually all the data

Comment: @MrPrinter OK ... let's try this: Please post your original code with the original header names. Do not translate it.

Comment: @Olaf , worked for me but without the spaces between [ and [int], and the int low case, and the headers with ' ' . Thank you very much. Appreciate your help.

Comment: Finally. Great.  ;-) :-D